# xsl: how to concatenate path for variable?

Tags: xslt, xpath, concatenation

I need to concatenate a path for a variable like this:

```
<xsl:variable name="foo" select="concat(//field_path_,$parameter,/data/*)" />
```

Doesn't work like that.

With `$parameter = "parametervalue"` the desired result would look like this:

```
<xsl:variable name="foo" select="//field_path_parametervalue/data/*" />
```

What's the right way to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<xsl:variable name="foo" 
  select="//*[name()=concat('field_path_',$parameter)]/data/*" />
```

Or perhaps better use a key. Note that XPath expressions are values not expression fragments, you can not build up an expression by string concatenation any more than you can increment a variable x by concatenating strings "x" and "+1" in C or Java etc. (XSLT 3 proposes an evaluate function which does evaluate a string as an xpath expression, but still you have to call an explicit evaluate function.)

Comment: ... five minutes after posting my question - what took you so long? =8)
Great, I'd never have guessed that (and I don't undestand it. can you recommend a good book?). What I have now (full code for my app) is
<xsl:variable name="smallcase" select="'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'" /><xsl:variable name="uppercase" select="'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'" />
<xsl:variable name="oh_am" select="//*[name()=concat('field_oh_',translate($oh_day, $uppercase, $smallcase),'_vormittag')]/data/*" />

Comment: @Ralf Michael Kay's book is _the_ book on xslt/xpath.